# Restrict S3-bucket from being changed to public?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to restrict a S3-bucket from being changed to public? Preferable do the prevention using cloudformation?

Comment: Are you creating the bucket via CloudFormation too? Are you wanting to defend against intentional configuration by an Admin, or unintentional action by an Admin?

Comment: Yes. And yes both? Is it just me or how often you want to go from private to public really? Then this might happened: https://securityboulevard.com/2018/01/leaky-buckets-10-worst-amazon-s3-breaches/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS just announced new features to block S3 bucket from being changed to public and also made the ability to scan your buckets with AWS Trusted Advisor free of charge. Read more on the blog: [Amazon S3 Block Public Access – Another Layer of Protection for Your Accounts and Buckets](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-block-public-access-another-layer-of-protection-for-your-accounts-and-buckets/)

Answer (score 1):

The AWS Security Blog features a post titled [How to Use AWS Config to Monitor for and Respond to Amazon S3 Buckets Allowing Public Access](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-aws-config-to-monitor-for-and-respond-to-amazon-s3-buckets-allowing-public-access/).

In short, the steps outlined in the post are:

1. Enable AWS Config to monitor Amazon S3 bucket ACLs and policies for
   compliance violations.
2. Create an IAM Role and Policy that grants a
   Lambda function permissions to read S3 bucket policies and send
   alerts through SNS.
3. Create and configure a CloudWatch Events rule
   that triggers the Lambda function when AWS Config detects an S3
   bucket ACL or policy violation.
4. Create a Lambda function that uses
   the IAM role to review S3 bucket ACLs and policies, correct the
   ACLs, and notify your team of out-of-compliance policies.
5. Verify the monitoring solution.